# How to correctly cancel requests after calling HttpListener.GetContextAsync()?

Tags: .net, vb.net, async-await, httplistener

I am struggling to close a HttpListener in a way that doesn't produce an IO exception.

It seems that I am either using HttpListener in an unusual way, or am missing something obvious.

I am setting up a HttpListener to listen for the redirect from an OAuth2.0 login.
I am attempting to start the listener, then open a web browser control to log in, then close the listener after actioning the redirect.

The code doesn't do all of that yet as I am trying to fix this error first.

If I close the login window to abort the login, and then try again but abort a second time, I get this error:

```
The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
System.Net.HttpListener.EndGetContext(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
BridgeIT.cOAuth2.VB$StateMachine_49_ListenForAuth.MoveNext() in xxx\cOAuth2.vb:line 235
```

I have tried using Begin/EndGetContext() methods instead, but they just produce the same result.

What am I missing?

This is my login function that is called from a button click event:

```
Public Function Login(ByVal vsLoginUrl As String, ByVal vsClientID As String, ByVal voScopes As IEnumerable(Of String)) As Boolean
        Dim bSuccess As Boolean = False
        Dim oAR As AuthenticationResult = Nothing
        Dim frm As frmOAuth2LoginDlg

        Dim sResponseType As String = "code"
        Dim sScope As String = String.Join(" ", voScopes)
        Dim sState As String = gsPracticeID
        Dim sCodeChallenge As String = GenerateCodeChallenge()
        Dim sCodeChallengeMethod As String = "S256"

        'Append query string params
        vsLoginUrl = $"{vsLoginUrl}?response_type={sResponseType}&client_id={vsClientID}&redirect_uri={msRedirectURL}&scope={sScope}&state={sState}&code_challenge={sCodeChallenge}&code_challenge_method={sCodeChallengeMethod}"
        Try
            'Listen for the the oAuth redirect
            ListenForAuth()

            'Open web browser control
            frm = New frmOAuth2LoginDlg(vsLoginUrl)
            frm.ShowDialog()

            'Do something after logging in

        Catch ex As Exception
            ShowError(Err.Number, Err.Description, ex)

        Finally
            CloseRedirectListener()
            DisposeOfObject(frm)
        End Try

    End Function
```

And the listener function:

```
Private Async Sub ListenForAuth()
        Dim oContext As HttpListenerContext
        Dim oRequest As HttpListenerRequest
        Dim oResponse As HttpListenerResponse

        moRedirectListener = New HttpListener
        moRedirectListener.Prefixes.Add(msRedirectURL)
        moRedirectListener.Start()

        Try
            oContext = Await moRedirectListener.GetContextAsync()

            oRequest = oContext.Request
            
            'Do something with the request

        Catch oex As ObjectDisposedException
            ' Safely ignore this if the listener has been closed
            ' Else rethrow the exception
            If oex.ObjectName <> "System.Net.HttpListener" Then
                Throw
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            ShowError(Err.Number, Err.Description, ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

And the CloseRedirectListener function:

```
    Private Sub CloseRedirectListener()
        If moRedirectListener IsNot Nothing Then
            moRedirectListener.Stop()
            moRedirectListener.Prefixes.Remove(msRedirectURL)
            moRedirectListener.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You can have a bogus redirect URL and catch it in the web browser control.

Comment: Have you looked at the examples in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener)?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for that exception?

Comment: @PauloMorgado I have added the stack trace to the question in an edit. I have read the docs yes. I can't find an example that stops the process whilst listening asynchronously though. It seems according to the docs I just need to call Stop() on the listener and then Close() when it's done. But when I call Stop() I get the IO error from GetContextAsync(). It seems very unusual to have to handle an exception to close the listener, hence the question.

Comment: What line is this? cOAuth2.vb:line 235

Comment: oContext = Await moRedirectListener.GetContextAsync()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be much movement on this question, so I'll post my solution for others until a better one is provided.

Catching the specific exceptions is the only way I have found to handle cancelled requests asynchronously:

```
Private Async Function ListenForAuth(frm As frmOAuth2LoginDlg) As Task
        Dim oContext As HttpListenerContext
        Dim oRequest As HttpListenerRequest

        moRedirectListener = New HttpListener

        moRedirectListener.Prefixes.Add(RedirectURL)
        moRedirectListener.Start()

        Try
            oContext = Await moRedirectListener.GetContextAsync()
            oRequest = oContext.Request

            ' Do something with the request

        ' Handle the exceptions in the case of cancelled requests
        Catch oObjectDisposedException As ObjectDisposedException
            ' If the Listener has been closed then safely ignore this
            ' Else rethrow
            If oObjectDisposedException.ObjectName <> "System.Net.HttpListener" Then
                Throw
            End If

        Catch oHttpListenerException As System.Net.HttpListenerException
            ' If the Listener has been stopped then safely ignore this
            ' Else rethrow
            If oHttpListenerException.Message <> "The I/O operation has been aborted because Of either a thread Exit Or an application request" Then
                Throw
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Do something with other exceptions

        Finally
            If Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of frmOAuth2LoginDlg).Count > 0 Then
                frm.Close()
            End If

        End Try

    End Function
```